# Select all class nodes except $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an event handler, where `$(this)` is an element that matches a `.myclass`

how do I select all other `.myclass` elements, except `$(this)`?

Comment: `$('.myclass').not(this)`

Comment: It's well worth your time reading through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) from beginning to end. It only takes about an hour, and it pays you back that time almost immediately.

Comment: Also, please do seach before posting a question. The question linked above was the third hit for the search "select elements except this" on A Famous Web Search Engine. (The others were variations on the theme, generally leading to `.not`.)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the other question not only marked as a drupal question with drupal code, but also the question and answer are not concise and direct. Directing others to a long question just because the answer is kind of the same and "generally leading to" the same answer does not contribute to people who need answers and want to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not()`:

```
$('.myclass').not(this)
```

Comment: that was fast, thanks